Can we use commands as a parameters?
I want to use the commands as parameters in a function.
Is there any way ?
import turtle as t

pen=t.Turtle

def orders(name,var) :
    pen.name(var)

orders(forward,50)
orders(right,90)
t.done()

I am expecting it will do ...
pen.forward(50)
pen.right(90)


Try it for yourself, then you can see if the error message makes sense to you. If you don't understand the error message, then you can come back here and ask about that.

You probably need to use the getattr function.

This isn't a good design. Why not call the methods directly?

The design you want is pointless. Just call the methods directly:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

t = Turtle()
t.forward(50)
t.right(90)
Screen().done()

...and always use instance mode, never call methods on the module.
You basically never need getattr, like you never need global or sys.setrecursionlimit. These are footgun features provided by the language that should be ignored, only leading to pain in the long run.

Any parameters passed to function must be defined, as the solution Mureinik said, you could pass the function as a string, since the functions you mentioned are instance method of a class, getattr is a prefer way for them.
However, as your question's title stated, a more generic way is to pass a function as a common parameter directly, of course, the function symbol must be exist before using it:
import turtle as t

pen=t.Turtle

def forward_pen(pen, var):
    pen.forward(var) 

def right_pen(pen, var):
    pen.right(var) 

def orders(funcp, var):
    funcp(pen, var)

orders(forward_pen, 50)
orders(right_pen, 90)
t.done()


You can use getattr to get the relevant function from its name:
import turtle as t

pen=t.Turtle()

def orders(name, var):
    if hasattr(pen name):
        getattr(pen, name)(var)

# Note that the names should be strings
orders('forward', 50)
orders('right', 90)
t.done()

